# Exclude certain posts with a high score from "low quality posts" in the review page

Tags: feature-request, review

This should be obvious.  If a post is helpful to others, it receives many upvotes, raising
its score.  Such a post is obviously hardly "low quality".  Especially if the asker accepted
  the post.  Unfortunately, a substantial amount of "low quality posts" on the review
page meet this criterion.

This is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?s=1&pagesize=15&filter=day&customsort=reverseorder&no-random=1) (using the Reverse Order sort ordering).

To address this, I make the following suggestions:

- Exclude posts with a score of 5 or more from the low quality posts.
- Optional:  Accepted answers can have a lower score threshold to be removed.
- Optional:  Posts from users with a certain reputation threshold can be removed
   with a lower score threshold.

These are only initial suggestions which can be modified if needed.  Please discuss this idea.

---

After reading another question on meta recently asked today, I will now suggest that the following posts should stay in the "low quality posts" tab, regardless of score:

- Answers to questions that are closed or have one or more close votes
- Answers to questions with a negative score

These should stay in because they tend to point to questions that themselves are low-quality. (Optionally those questions should be mentioned on the page along with their score and, for users with the "view close votes" privilege, the number of close votes.)

Comment: Have these particular posts been harshly dealt with?

Comment: @Robert Harvey: No, such posts merely detract from finding the posts which probably truly are low quality.  Those tend to have a negative or zero score or have content problems that "can't be salvageable through editing."

Answer (score 2):

I see, you're referring to the algorithmic check, which is largely based on length. Short "answers".

I am not sure I entirely agree; if a question is "answered" with something absurdly short enough to trigger the quality filter like 3 - 5 words, that implies there was a fundamental problem with the question, as in, perhaps the question was too trivial to begin with?

For example

[How to find if directory exists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933237/how-to-find-if-directory-exists-in-python)

> Yes, use os.path.exists().

is a valid "answer", but was algorithmically determined to be possibly low quality. (Note that this is *not* a flag, just a numeric score attached to the answer.) However, if you check the comments:

> A good approach is always to search since that's been asked.

Therefore this flag is symptomatic of a deeper problem. This has always been my position on flagging: **where there is smoke, there is generally fire**. For some reason people get obsessed with deciding exactly what kind of fire this is, when there's a giant raging fire going on on the background. How 'bout we put out the fire, man?

Comment: Your point is somewhat valid: the "low quality posts" tab gives no clues on whether a question is *already answered*, especially for "fastest-gun questions" (and I'm not sure it should.)

Comment: go deeper: we shouldn't be encouraging questions than *can actually be properly and completely answered in 3-5 words!*